# Using zlib under windows mingw

Tags: c, windows, mingw, zlib

I can't seem to get zlib to do anything on mingw under windows.

I downloaded zlib @  http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files_beta/MinGW/zlib/zlib-1.2.3-1-mingw32/ and put the header and lib files in the right place.

Simple code like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "zlib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long a;
    char buffer[1024];
    a = 1024;
    compress(buffer,&a,"testing",7);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled:

```
gcc test.c -lzlib -Wall -o test.exe
```

Compiles fine.
However the exe crashes at the compress function.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) for this kind of thing.  These instructions assume you want to compile a 64-bit program, but they can easily be modified for 32-bit.

After installing MSYS2, run the "MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell" shortcut in your Start Menu.  Install the 64-bit toolchain by running:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
```

Then compile your code by running something like this:

```
gcc test.c -lz -o test
```

I did not check your code carefully, but I was able to run your code without any crashing, so your code might be OK.  Your code also gives no output so it's hard to tell if it really worked.

Comment: Do you understand why you should `-lz` instead of `-lzlib`? I've seen that the zlib package installs a `libz.a` file (and a `libz.dl.al`) but I haven't figured out why it's different on this system. For me, it matters because I'm installing a python package, lxml, which I cannot modify.

Comment: Well, the linker automatically prepends `lib` to library names, so `-lz` is the correct option if you want to link to `libz.a`.  If some other software is trying to use `-lzlib` (instead of doing the proper thing and running `pkg-config zlib --libs` to figure out the arguments), and you are unable to configure that software to use the correct arguments, then I suppose you could copy `libz.a` to `libzlib.a` as a hacky workaround.

Comment: Thankfully, copying the file to the new name caused the compilation to succeed. I'm still not convinced that it's supposed to be the same file, but I'll find out soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the zlib manual it says:

> ```
> ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT compress OF((Bytef *dest, uLongf *destLen,
>                            const Bytef *source, uLong sourceLen));
> ```
>
> Compresses the source buffer into the
>   destination buffer. sourceLen is the
>   byte length of the source buffer. Upon
>   entry, destLen is the total size of
>   the destination buffer, which must be
>   at least the value returned by
>   compressBound(sourceLen). Upon exit,
>   destLen is the actual size of the
>   compressed buffer.

Maybe `a=1024` isn't big enough? I think you need to call `compressBound` to get a suitable value.

Comment: For some reason I found that mingw has a zlib library and libz library. When I use libz, everything works. I don't really know what the differences are or why the name is backwards, oh wells. The manual says the output buffer only has to be 12 bytes more than the input, as that is worst case compression (10 byte header and 2 bytes to say no compression?). It works now with libz instead of zlib. Infact I think the zlib library files are files that some how got accidently installed along time ago from a missconfiguration. (p.s. To mods: the answer your own question button doesn't work for me?!)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the zlib from MSYS (accessible with mingw-get) and got the same problem as described below.

The solution is to do a static link instead of using the shared library.
Just remove or rename the import library libz.dll.a to avoid the linker to do a link with the msys-z.dll.

Recompile and it will be working.

Another way is to install zlib yourself from the zlib.net website.
Remove the one from mingw-get.

Answer (score 0):

Using zlib in your code is extremely simple, something that the documentation ( or the various answers on stackoverflow I found ) don't make obvious.

The following technique works for any compiler and IDE.  I tested it in windows mingw using code:blocks, which is why I am posting it as an answer to this question.

1. Download the zlib source code from http://www.zlib.net/
2. Copy all the .c and .h files from the root folder of the zlib source to a folder in your compiler search path.
3. Add the zlib source files to the IDE project.
4. Add #include "zlib.h" to your source code
5. Call compress or uncompress

That's it.  It could hardly be simpler.

All you have to be careful about is memory management, since this is c code.

To make things even simpler for myself, I have put together a c++ wrapper which you are welcome to use, like this:

```
/** ZLIB C++ wrapper

Usage:

<pre>

    #include "cZLIB.h"

    {
    // compress data in bigbuffer
    raven::set::cZLIB ZLIB;
    ZLIB.Compress( bigbuffer, sizebigbuffer );

    // use compressed buffer, before ZLIB goes out of scope
    use( ZLIB.Buffer(), ZLIB.Length() );

    }

    ...

    {

    // decompress data in smallbuffer
    raven::set::cZLIB ZLIB;
    ZLIB.Inflate( smallbuffer, sizesmallbuffer )

    // use decompressed data, before ZLIB goes out of scope
    use( ZLIB.Buffer(), ZLIB.Length() );

    }

</pre>

Build:

Download this code ( cZLIB.h and cZLIB.cpp ) from

https://github.com/JamesBremner/raven-set

and install somewhere in your compiler search path.
Let's assume you install it in folder .../src.

Download the zlib source code from http://www.zlib.net/
Copy all the .c and .h files from the root folder of the zlib source
to a new folder .../src/zlib

Add the files cZLIB.h, cZLIB.cpp and all the files in .../src/zlib
to the IDE project.

Build.

 */
class cZLIB
...
```

Comment: This is a description of how to _vendorize_ zlib. They want to use the system's zlib, not their own privately tracked and updated version.