# How To Add zlib1.dll to MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, zlib

I am brand new to C++, although I know java pretty well, and I trying to set up compiler. I managed to download MinGW and modify my Path environmental variable. I am not at the point where when I go into the command prompt and type:

```
g++ --version
```

I get what Sam-s Teach Yourself C++ in 24 Hours says I should. But when I type:

```
g++ Hello.cpp -o Hello.exe
```

I get an error message that says "The program can't start because zlib1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem". I tried reinstalling multiple times, but nothing changed. Looking on [Stack Overflow](https://superuser.com/questions/789397/mingw-gcc-missing-zlib1-dll), I found that this is apparently a fairly common problem, and you have to add it to the file yourself.

I downloaded the file, but I can find/figure out where I am suppose to put it. The folder I downloaded is called zlib128-dll and it contains (among other things) the file zlib1.dll, which I think is what I want. What do I do with what to make the error message go away?

Other information:
-Using Windows 8.1
-I think I got the newest version of MinGW, since I just got it about 2 hours ago

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Using zlib under windows mingw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163170/using-zlib-under-windows-mingw)

Comment: First of all, that doesn't even have an answer to the asked question. Secondly, that is about it missing it, not where to add it. If anything, that unanswered question should be replaced with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you put `zlib1.dll` in any folder listed in `path` variable (or in the same folder with MinGW executable). I think, best way is to put it right into `MinGW\bin`.

Comment: Do I move to other folders that are with it there as well? (include, lib, and test)

Comment: No, I think you need only that .dll.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks very much. It works great! I would up-vote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation... :(